# Messages is processing an incoming message

Tags: google-messages

When there is an incoming SMS, my phone would show "Messages is processing an incoming message" in the notification drawer, but then that notification would disappear and... nothing! There is no notifications for the actual SMS. When I opened Messages, I couldn't see that incoming SMS. I checked the web interface for Messages, not there either. Couldn't find it in the "Spam & blocked" or Archived either.

[image: Messages is processing an incoming message]

I need to read this SMS for two factor authentication. I would wait for the SMS to appear, but most of the time it didn't appear until the authentication code expired. I had to request auth code 2 or 3 times before I got it in time.

Is there a way to get SMS quicker?

Android version 9. Device is Asus Zenfone Max Pro M1. Messages version 9.2.030.

Comment: I'm having the same issue (and coincidentally we're in the same country, perhaps a provider-dependent issue?). My current workaround is to open the web interface before requesting the OTP, and while it might not always succeed, I observed I often got the SMS a bit quicker (i.e. originally from more than 5-minute delay to more bearable 2-minute delay). Not yet found the cause and permanent fix...

Comment: @AndrewT. wah salam kenal! Don't think it is Indosat's problem, because that "Messages is processing an incoming message" popped up pretty quickly. Maybe google should add more servers for Messages.
Thanks for the tip, I'll try it next time.

Comment: Surprisingly, my provider is *also* Indosat :) but this only happens on my old Nexus 5 (Lineage OS 14, Android 7), not on a quite new Pixel 3a (Android 11). I haven't got a chance to test with other providers though, or re-flash my Nexus and see if there's any improvement...

Comment: It is possible that the received SMS was an MMS. As far as I remember an MMS is a special SMS containing a link where to fetch the MMS content. If fetching the MMS content fails then such a behavior as you have observed would be possible.

Comment: i have telkomsel. i can confirm i have this problem. its an otp request sms, which have very limited time to input. its very pain

Comment: I have this issue as well.
Living in Jakarta; using XL Axiata, Xiaomi A1. I thought this problem is from my banking OTP, but it is confirmed & tested that any kind of incoming SMS will give the same exact problem with the original poster. It is not only OTP guys... As long as it is through SMS, it is a problem. Some application gives you OTP through WhatsApp, then it is not a problem.

Comment: Same here. XL or Indosat. Its all the same..

Comment: For what it's worth. I've seen this message on European phone networks as well. I think it's just that your phone is underpowered for Messages. I have a Nokia 1 Plus as a spare phone, and it's tediously slow (to the point I can barely pick up the phone when someone calls me before they hang up). That phone shows that message pretty regularly.

Comment: Hi guys, I'm living in Germany and sometimes coming back home to Indonesia for a longer period of visit. I can only confirm that the issue persists regardless of the country I'm in. I suppose it's got more something to do with the hardware than the network provider. I'm on Pixel 2 (Android 11, rooted) and it suffers from this issue. When I'm on my old Nexus 5X tho, it works just fine. Have you guys tried to **clear the cache & data of the Messages app** and/or **reset network settings**? Haven't tried it myself, just concerned if it's gonna make things worse... 

Comment: @AndrewT. Just out of curiosity: which "web interface" were you referring to in your comment to "roll the dice" for the workaround? ...and are you still having this issue? 

Comment: @GlennMohammad I was using Google Messages, and it has [the web interface](https://messages.google.com/web/). My Nexus 5 went dead already, but I didn't have any issues with a new budget phone.

Comment: @AndrewT. Returning to Europe this summer; I believe I found a way to enhance just enough your workaround to get by. Now I can receive SMS "normally" again within 2-3 seconds window. I'll write something down as a possible solution to this issue. Thaanks a lot! :`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hardware Performance?

It could be that your phone is underpowered.

Your mention a Asus Zenfone Max Pro M1, which is a mid-range phone from 2018. So I wouldn't think it's *THAT* slow, but I definitely see this message occur on underpowered devices (including one of mine, a Nokia 1 Plus), and depending on your setup it be the cause.

I'd recommend you try to "lighten" your phone a bit:

- remove useless apps (to ensure enough available memory to run smoothly),
- replace some apps with lighter versions (for instance, I use Android GO versions of Google Apps when possible, and I use Olauncher as a minimalist launcher),
- disable background tasks where/when possible.

### Network / Operator Performance?

I don't think it's related to the phone network operator.

I get these on different networks with that phone. And I have not issues when I use other phones on these networks.

Comment: Just a note, I bought a new phone and with this new phone the SMS appears quickly. So the solution is buy a new phone :D

Comment: @EndyTjahjono: nah... ;)

Comment: This happens to me on my new pixel 6 pro

Answer (score 1):

As of June 2023, here's how I managed to make this infamous "Messages is processing an incoming message" issue resolved on my Pixel 2 (running a rooted Android 11 ):

1. Upgrade to the latest Messages app.
2. Open https://messages.google.com/web in your Google Chrome on your Android device (yes, it's gotta be on the corresponding Android device where you got the issue, otherwise it won't do). Check on "Remember this computer", take the screenshot of the QR code.
3. Quickly send this QR code screenshot to your own self on WhatsApp/Telegram/Signal or similar app (the idea here is to be able to open this QR code on another machine via WhatsApp/Telegram Web/Desktop so that you can scan it using your phone).
4. Using your PC or Mac, open the chat-to-yourself containing the QR code screenshot from the previous step on e.g. WhatsApp Web. While leaving it open, open the Messages app on the problematic phone, go to "Device pairing" and scan the aforementioned QR code.
5. Now that your Messages app and Chrome for Android are paired on the same phone, open again https://messages.google.com/web in your Chrome (on your phone) and verify that the Messages Web works correctly there.
6. Lastly, click on the Chrome's menu while opening the Messages Web tab, and select "Add to Home screen" – this will add "Messages Web" to your phone's home screen.
7. After this **pairing act between your Messages app and Chrome for Android** on your phone, you should be able to receive messages/SMS normally again within 2-3 seconds window! ⚡️

I believe the pairing act forces the messages/SMS checking mechanics to be constantly executed somehow by the Messages app:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get theses kinds of messages by simply downloading a new messaging app that carries over your current messages. I personally had access to Verizon's messenger+ which worked fine for me. Hope this helps

Comment: It's good to know that your issue was able to be solved only by changing a messaging app, though I have tried this before many times and it didn't change the result :')

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's the phone problem. I recently change my phone and now it take years for the sms to came in. Previously with the old phone, I can receive sms normally

Comment: I also strongly believe that it's the hardware problem. Yet, I cannot 100% prove it... (still hope that it is not somehow)

Comment: Nvm. I found a solution (workaround) that works reliably now :D
https://android.stackexchange.com/a/252565/261045